# VB.NET: Reading a string of chat messages

Tags: vb.net, string, chat, data-extraction

I've made a program that reads chat messages from a website and displays them in a richtextbox in a certain format:

```
You're now chatting with a random stranger. Say hi!
You: Hi
Stranger: hi
Stranger has disconnected.
```

The richtextbox is updated each time a message is sent. **I'm trying to create a string array containing the messages the Stranger sends.** So each time Stranger sends a new message, it gets added to the array. Here's what I've tried so far:

First I made sure to get rid of unnecessary messages such as system messages:

```
  Dim AvoidList() As String = {"Really?", " or turn on video", " My language  English", " Find strangers with common interests (Enable)", "New", "Stop", "Esc", "Send", "Enter", "You're now chatting with a random stranger. Say hi!", "Stranger is typing...", "Connecting to server...", "Great chat? Save the log: Get a link • Select all • Or post log to: Facebook • Tumblr • Twitter • reddit"}
        If Log.Text.Contains("You're now chatting with a random stranger. Say hi!") Or Log.Text.StartsWith("Stranger: ") Or Log.Text.StartsWith("You: ") Then
            While (i < AvoidList.Length)
                If Log.Text.Contains(AvoidList(i)) Then
                    Log.Text = Log.Text.Replace(AvoidList(i), "")
                End If
                i += 1
            End While
```

Then I attempted to put every line in a part of my string array called `Messages` while ignoring empty lines, then attempted to store the strings containing only the word "Stranger:" in a second string called `StrangerMessages`, but for some reason the second array remains empty:

```
 Messages = Log.Text.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                i = 0
                While (i < Messages.Length)
                    If Messages(i).Contains("Stranger:") Then
                        StrangerMessages(j) = Messages(i)
                        TTB.Text = TTB.Text & StrangerMessages(j) & vbNewLine
                        j += 1
                    End If
                    i += 1
                End While
```

What am I doing wrong there? Also is there a better way to get it done?